# Mocking only specific code line inside whole method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, robolectric

I have code where I want to test a method, but to mock only a specific part inside that method, for instance, I want to call to `doNetworkWork` and do it completely and only return specific behavior on the call to: `mRestPR.callNetwork(restCall)` so if there will be some issues before that call I want it to succeed/failed.

```
  @Test
    public void testMethod () {
        Services sr = new Services ();
        sr.doNetworkWork(new CallackService() {
               @Override
                public void onComplete(String response ){
                //do some work
    }});
   }
```

`Services.java`

```
public void doNetworkWork (CallackService  callback) {

    RestCall restCall = new RestCall (RestMethodType.POST, uri, ADD_77, new 
    RestCall.RestCallListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Response response) {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onComplete(response.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

             // some work
             // mRestPR – private member
            mRestPR.callNetwork(restCall);
    }
```

Comment: It looks to me like you want to mock `mRestPR` and stub `callNetwork`.

Comment: thats correct, for some reason when I'm trying to mock it if fails in one of the other calls inside the `mRestPR` methods

Comment: Well, you haven't really shown enough code to help anyone work out why.  How do you set up your mock, and how do you inject it into the object you're testing?

Comment: Haven't shown code? so what did I add? I don't use mockups, I use `Robolectirc` - thats what gives me the possibility to create object and use it as normal, this is my questions how can I "inject" specific behavior as a private member inside tested method - `mRestPR.callNetwork(restCall)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that many times when you're in the dilemma, it's a design flaw. In this case, the doNetworkNow method probably belongs in a separate object and then you would be able to Mock normally.

I can't tell for sure, because you've not provided enough code for me to give good counsel.